# ReCaptcha problems in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I have followed the directions posted on [ReCaptcha's site](https://bitbucket.org/mml/ruby-recaptcha/wiki/Home) about integrating Recaptcha into my application. However when I go to view it on my localhost I just get the code for get_captcha() instead of the widget. I have made the public keys available in my environment.rb file, added the recaptcha::apphelper to my application controller, and chained my vaildation, I have also included the recaptcha::viewhelper to my application helper. Am I missing a step in adding it, or is there another resource that would make this work better?

Comment: Could you explain how it's not working by showing us what you see?

Comment: I just get this code: get_captcha(:options => {:theme => 'white', :tabindex => 10}) instead of the widget showing up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view you must use an ERB output block (`<%=`) to make this output the captcha:

```
<%= raw(get_captcha(:options => {:theme => 'white', :tabindex => 10) %>
```

Anything not in this (or it's brother, the ERB evaluation block (`<%`)) will be treated as plain text.

Comment: Ok... now I get: <script type="text/javascript"> var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : "white", tabindex : 10}; </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LdK-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxin-yMM2-R9ZZvd-AWoV"> </script> <noscript> <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6LdK-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxin-yMM2-R9ZZvd-AWoV" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br> <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"> </textarea> <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"> </noscript>, and no widget

Comment: @demondeac11: You will have to use `raw`, as Rails 3 automatically escapes content. It would appear this plugin is not doing that automatically. The answer has been updated.